# Why eslint gives an error message when any enum present in types.ts?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a project with Vue3, Quasar, Typescript & Eslint.
When I've added a enum in my types file, like this:

```
/* eslint-disable */
export type TableFieldType = 'default' | 'expandable' | 'editable' | 'button' | 'custom' | 'json';

export type Selection = 'select' | 'multiselect' | undefined;

export enum SortDirection {
  'asc' = 1, 'desc' = -1, 'nd' = 0
}
```

node started to give a very strange error:

```
[eslint] Node must be provided when reporting error if location is not provided
Occurred while linting /home/hvedrung/projects/table-component/src/types.ts:2
```

(the line 2 because code start from this line. If I remove comment in the line 1, error will refer to line 1. It don't like the types.ts at all)

If I remove enum error disappearing.

What I've tried:

- added /* eslint-disable */ in types.ts
- added "no-shadow": "off" to eslint rules
- tried to move enum in another file - in this case error contains reference to file with enum

With no any result.

Had anybody seen such error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the full text of the ESLint error? Specifically, we will need to know the lint rule that's reporting to know best how to help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solve the issue.
Just removed quotes in enum keys. I don't know why it works so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It seems that export enum SortDirection {
  'asc' = 1, 'desc' = -1, 'nd' = 0
} must be written export enum SortDirection {
 'asc = 1, desc = -1, nd = 0
}